# VBA - How to keep a Dynamic FormulaR1C1 that evaluates?

Tags: vba, excel

I've been at this for days now. I have tried everything from stringing the formulae to using FormulaR1C1 and evaluate.

I have something close to 35000+rows of data and want to limit the time the calculation takes and also the time taken to filter through colours etc.(conditional formatting)

I was hoping for a code that would allow me to "update (button)" and just populate the result and not the formulae across all rows.

Please see my excel formulae:

```
=IF(D2>0,1,0)+IF(E2>0,1,0)+IF(F2>0,1,0)+IF(G2>0,1,0)
=IF(SUMIF(B:B,B2,D:D)>0,1,0)+IF(SUMIF(B:B,B2,E:E)>0,1,0)+IF(SUMIF(B:B,B2,F:F)>0,1,0)+IF(SUMIF(B:B,B2,G:G)>0,1,0)+IF(SUMIF(B:B,B2,H:H)>0,1,0)
=IF(B2=B1,C2-C1,0)
```

I have tried the following -

```
Sub COLUMNS2stringg()

 Dim strFormulas(1 To 3) As Variant

With ThisWorkbook.Sheets("working")
   strFormulas(1) = "=IF(RC[-5]>0,1,0)+IF(RC[-4]>0,1,0)+IF(RC[-3]>0,1,0)+IF(RC[-2]>0,1,0)"
    strFormulas(2) = "=IF(SUMIF(C[-8],RC[-8],C[-6])>0,1,0)+IF(SUMIF(C[-8],RC[-8],C[-5])>0,1,0)+IF(SUMIF(C[-8],RC[-8],C[-4])>0,1,0)+IF(SUMIF(C[-8],RC[-8],C[-3])>0,1,0)+IF(SUMIF(C[-8],RC[-8],C[-2])>0,1,0)"
    strFormulas(3) = "=IF(RC[-9]=R[-1]C[-9],RC[-8]-R[-1]C[-8],0)"
    .Range("i3:k3").Formula = strFormulas
    .Range("i3:k35000").FillDown
End With

End Sub
```

I have also tried the following -

```
Sub COLUMNS2()

Range("I3").Select
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=IF(RC[-5]>0,1,0)+IF(RC[-4]>0,1,0)+IF(RC[-3]>0,1,0)+IF(RC[-2]>0,1,0)"
Range("i3:i35000" & lrow).FillDown
Range("J3").Select
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=IF(SUMIF(C[-8],RC[-8],C[-6])>0,1,0)+IF(SUMIF(C[-8],RC[-8],C[-5])>0,1,0)+IF(SUMIF(C[-8],RC[-8],C[-4])>0,1,0)+IF(SUMIF(C[-8],RC[-8],C[-3])>0,1,0)+IF(SUMIF(C[-8],RC[-8],C[-2])>0,1,0)"
Range("j3:j35000" & lrow).FillDown
Range("K3").Select
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=IF(RC[-9]=R[-1]C[-9],RC[-8]-R[-1]C[-8],0)"
Range("k3:k35000" & lrow).FillDown

End Sub
```

I have also tried -

```
 Sub overit2()

Dim strFormulas(1 To 3) As Variant
With ThisWorkbook.Sheets("working")
    strFormulas(1) = "=IF("$D3">0,1,0)+IF("$E3">0,1,0)+IF($F3>0,1,0)+IF($G3>0,1,0)"
    strFormulas(2) = "=IF(SUMIF(B:B,$B3,D:D)>0,1,0)+IF(SUMIF(B:B,$B3,E:E)>0,1,0)+IF(SUMIF(B:B,$B3,F:F)>0,1,0)+IF(SUMIF(B:B,$B3,G:G)>0,1,0)+IF(SUMIF(B:B,$B3,H:H)>0,1,0)"
    strFormulas(3) = "=IF($B3=$B2,$C3-$C2,0)"
    .Range("j3").Formula = strFormulas(1)
    .Range("j3:j35000" & lrow).FillDown
    .Range("k3").Formula = strFormulas(2)
    .Range("k3:k35000" & lrow).FillDown
    .Range("l3").Formula = strFormulas(3)
    .Range("l3:l35000" & lrow).FillDown
 End With

 End Sub
```

Where am I going wrong? I have tried a magnitude of variations :( please help

Comment: The first formula could be simplified to `=countif(D2:G2,">0")` and would calculate much faster than the series of IF statements.

Answer (score 0):

So the problem is that it is very slow and you need to make it work faster right?

35000 rows is not that much. Most of these ways of applying formulas should not be too slow, but here are some tips I can give without knowing anything else about your excel file.

1) Use these to reduce computational time

```
Application.Calculation = xlManual   'In the beginning of the code
Application.Calculation = xlAutomatic  'In the end of the code
```

This will not calculate all formulas each time there is a minor modification and will calculate it only once

2) Make sure that your file size is as small as possible. Look at your scroll bar is small and it scrolls till 500000 rows/colums but u don't have data beyond 35000 then excel is creating a lot of blank rows which take up space. Delete them and save the file, the scroll bar should be much bigger

3) Improve formulas. For example the second formula that you have is looking at all rows of B when you do B:B which is about a million rows where as you have data only till 35,000 rows! use B1:B35000 instead. In fact I think there should be a much better way of writing the second formula. Maybe getting all the distinct values of B2 which might be 100 rows and then after calculating the flags, doing a VLOOKUP for the 35000 rows using only B2

4) If you have other VBA code as well then add

```
Application.ScreenUpdating = False 'in the beginning of the code
Application.ScreenUpdating = False 'In the end of the code
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, it appears this formula (=IF(SUMIF(B:B,B2,D:D)>0,1,0)+IF(SUMIF(B:B,B2,E:E)>0,1,0)+IF(SUMIF(B:B,B2,F:F)>0,1,0)+IF(SUMIF(B:B,B2,G:G)>0,1,0)+IF(SUMIF(B:B,B2,H:H)>0,1,0)) is taking the longest to calculate, I have actually inherited this sheet from someone else and deleting the formulae from row 35000 to forever and ever was actually the first thing I did :). I am attempting to (a) make it much quicker to run (b) make it easier for the end user to manipulate the data , (with filtering etc.)

Comment: it is taking anywhere up to 15 mins to manipulate the data for processing based on 3 columns worth of results and almost 20 criteria results.